# CentOS how to update Ant Version to 1.8.x and higher?

Tags: centos, yum, repository, ant

I'm using CentOS 6.5 and installed `Ant` by using:

```
yum install ant
```

It came with Ant version 1.7.1, but I need the latest -- version 1.8.0.

- How to properly get the latest `Ant version 1.8.x` (or higher) from `YUM` or any way please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Awk's answer may probably work, but for some reason, it's not working for me. Then i found this (a bit different) answer by Googling.

1. Download “bin” Release from http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
2. Extract & copy/move the whole folder (apache-ant-1.9xxxxx) into `/opt/`. So there will be `/opt/apache-ant-1.9xxxxxx/`
3. Make a Symlink: `ln -s /opt/apache-ant-1.9.xxxxx /opt/ant`
4. Make another Symlink: `ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/bin/ant`
5. Set `ANT_HOME` into the Environment `vi /etc/environment` and add this line: `ANT_HOME=/opt/ant` *(without trailing slash)*
6. Re-login to initiate the Environment.

That one perfectly works for me.

Comment: Works fine for me, but I didn't need to edit `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from 夏期劇場 works, but it has few extra steps that aren't strictly necessary. The following configuration worked for me compiling Solr.

Download and extract ant into /opt/ant

```
$ sudo -i
# cd /opt
# wget http://apache.parentingamerica.com//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.6-bin.tar.bz2
# tar xjf apache-ant-1.9.6-bin.tar.bz2
# mv apache-ant-1.9.6 ant
```

Remove any existing ant packages

```
# yum remove -y `rpm -qa | grep '^ant-'`
```

Create symlink to ant executable

```
# ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/local/bin/ant
```

If you want ant to be available for root user, then create symlink to ant executable from /usr/local/sbin

```
# ln -s /opt/ant/bin/ant /usr/local/sbin/ant
```

Logout out of the system and log back in, command `ant` should be available for you to use.

Comment: This works fine, but don't copy the exact commands unless you _really_ want v.1.9.6! Go to http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi to download the version you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can download the tarball from here

1. Download binary file http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/
2. Extract `tar -xvf apache-ant-1.x.x.tar.gz`
3. move to its location `mv apache-ant-1.x.x /opt/bin`
4. set ant path in `/etc/profile` or in you `.bashrc` that is `export ANT_HOME=/opt/ant`

Once it's done check out the `ant` version by using `ant -version`

Comment: Move to `/opt/bin` or `/opt/ant`, please? (I do not find `opt/bin`)

Comment: Sorry it was `/opt/ant`, actually you can keep binary in any location, but `export ANT_HOME=your/binary/path` in `/etc/profile` or `.bashrc` is important.